# How to override Google Maps onMarkerClick while keeping original functionality

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

By default, Maps pans to a marker and gives you a little info bubble when you click on it. I want to keep this behaviour but make it so it also does something else (like display a toast under certain conditions). When I override this method, it removes the original functionality completely. Can I keep the original functionality while adding new behaviour? Or is the source code for doing that pan+dialog available somewhere so I can copy parts of it into my function?

I am setting the listener with:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
```

and my override function is just simply in the form of:

```
override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
    // Do something extra here
    return true
}
```

Comment: Return 'false' and the default behavior will occur.

Comment: Perfect! How come that works?

Comment: Because the documentation says it will?  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.  I'm not a kotlin programmer and I don't see any kotlin specific google map api docs - so I can only assume the standard docs apply in all cases - but that seems like trouble.

Comment: Totally missed that in the docs, thanks